# getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, proxy

Hi guys I'm trying to publish my angular library in npm, but when I login I get this:

```sh
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/-/user/org.couchdb.user:belzee10 failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\belzee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-08T16_03_35_050Z-debug.log
```

versions

```sh
node: 8.9.3
npm: 5.5.1
```

I am behind an authenticated proxy and I have already configured: proxy and https-proxy

```sh
npm config set proxy http: // Username: Pa55w0rd @ proxyhostname: port
npm config set https-proxy http: // Username: Pa55w0rd @ proxyhostname: port
```

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 14):

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Use the above commands and restart the system. It worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

This drove me crazy for hours and I didn't even know what I did to make it work. But the last thing I tried was:

In cmd typed `ping registry.npmjs.org`.
Error couldn't find the host

Open hosts file through this: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/

Added `151.101.72.162 registry.npmjs.org` to a new line.
Save.

Tried installing a package, still didn't work

But I randomly tried to `ping registry.npmjs.org` again, and it worked!

Tried installing a package again, still didn't work.

Removed the `151.101.72.162 registry.npmjs.org` and saved again. Practically reverting the last edit.

Tried installing and it's working now. Why???? I have no idea. For all I know there's a minor deity inside my laptop and I randomly appeased it somehow...

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem in a `WSL1` Linux container on a Windows 10 host in a corporate network.

Adding a new nameserver to the top of `/etc/resolv.conf` as either `9.9.9.9` or `1.1.1.1` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The following github link resolved the issue for me ->

https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/issues/270#issuecomment-382229052

create the file /etc/docker/daemon.json

and insert:

```
{
    "dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

and then restarting pc

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect to some other network.

This error resemble some issue with network. I was trying to install a lib from NPM on windows but getting this error. This worked for me. Maybe it might help you too.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by simply adding nameserver into the netplan script. This worked for me without any issue.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp2s0:
     addresses:
        - 192.168.0.241/24
     routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.12
     nameservers:
         addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
  version: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First run
`npm i npm@latest`
and check error is coming again or not. if it is
Try to resolve your proxy settings

For Linux(ubuntu)
https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/

For windows
https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-set-your-proxy-settings-in-windows-8.1/

Answer (score 0):

1. Changed the registry as *https://registry.npmjs.org/* in *.npmrc* file.

In terminal:

1. npm config rm proxy
2. npm config rm https-proxy
3. Restarted the system.
   npm i worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, there must have been network instability, I deactivated then reactivated my internet connection, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same with WSL2 and node_version- 16.14.0 npm_version- 8.3.1 and fixed with modifying **/etc/resolv.conf** with  adding new nameserver as 9.9.9.9 or 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score -1):

That error means a domain name resolution error in Node.
I'm not sure what exactly could be your issue here, but https://www.codingdefined.com/2015/06/nodejs-error-errno-eaiagain.html has some good info. 
This error is definitely due to the proxy you have set up. I had a similar issue earlier, and disabling the proxy worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem you can check if you opening a session  that connecting database, you can try disabling any sessions on the database and try again using  npm i filepond